The tag "o" : Which type of questions
I do not understand the o tag. Which topics does it refer to?

It's very likely the Big O notation. I guess [big-o] would be nicer. At math is has the tag [asymptotics]. Note that tags are automatically created when used.

That was a plain accidental typo! I removed it from the question. I hope the system will heal and remove it. If we need a tag for that, I second big-o.

More like a type-O if you ask me :P
